# self-adjoint operator $L = *D + D*$ on 3-manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

In [Witten Quantum Field Theory and the Jones Polynomial](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/beem/papers/jones_polynomial_witten.pdf), he mentioned,

Let $D$ be the exterior derivative on M, twisted by the fiat connection $A$ let $*$ be the Hodge operator that maps $k$ forms to $3-k$ forms. On a three manifold one has a natural self-adjoint operator
$$L = *D + D*$$
which maps differential forms of even order to forms of even order and forms of odd order to forms of odd order. Let $L_-$ denote its restriction to forms of odd order.

In $d$-dimension (say $d=3$),

- isn't that $*D$ maps a $k$ form to $d-k-1$-form?
- isn't that $D*$ maps a $k$ form to $d-k+1$-form?

So $L = *D + D*$ on $k$-form $V$ produce $LV$ with both $d-k-1$-form and $d-k+1$-form?
how can this $L$ operator be natural?

- Say $d=3, k=0$, we get $d-k-1=2$-form and $d-k+1=4$-form?
- Say $d=3, k=1$, we get $d-k-1=1$-form and $d-k+1=3$-form?
- Say $d=3, k=2$, we get $d-k-1=0$-form and $d-k+1=2$-form?
- Say $d=3, k=3$, we get $d-k-1=-1$-form and $d-k+1=1$-form?

Comment: With respect to what inner product is this operator supposed to be self adjoint?

Answer (score 1):

Letting

\begin{align*}
\Omega^{\bullet}(M) &= \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\dim M}\Omega^k(M)\\
\Omega^{\text{even}}(M) &= \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\lfloor\dim M/2\rfloor}\Omega^{2k}(M)\\
\Omega^{\text{odd}}(M) &= \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\lfloor\dim M/2\rfloor}\Omega^{2k+1}(M),
\end{align*}

we have $\Omega^{\bullet}(M) = \Omega^{\text{even}}(M)\oplus\Omega^{\text{odd}}(M)$.

The operator $L : \Omega^{\bullet}(M) \to \Omega^{\bullet}(M)$ satisfies $L|_{\Omega^{\text{even}}(M)} : \Omega^{\text{even}}(M) \to \Omega^{\text{even}}(M)$ and $L|_{\Omega^{\text{odd}}(M)} : \Omega^{\text{odd}}(M) \to \Omega^{\text{odd}}(M)$.

In particular, if $\alpha \in \Omega^p(M)$, then $L(\alpha)$ need not be a differential form of pure degree, but it is the sum of such forms whose degrees have the same parity as $p$ does.